# How do I set checkboxes programatically in a profile?

Tags: 7, users

I've added a new checkbox list to my profile, and now need to import new profile from an XML file.

my checkboxes look like this....

```
Subscribed
[x] A
[ ] B
[x] C
[ ] D
```

If the XML shows they are subscribed to "A" and "C" how do I set this in the new new profile?

I'm doing simple fields like this...

```
$new_user = array(
  'name' => $node->Username,
  'pass' => $node->Password, 
  'mail' => $node->EmailAddress,
  'status' => 1,
  'init' => $email,
  'roles' => array(
        DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID => 'authenticated user',
        3 => 'custom role',
  ),
  // Simple fields like this...
  'field_first_name' => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' => $node->FirstName))),
  );

user_save('', $new_user);
```

But how to do it for checkboxes...